# Create one navbar and use it on different pages with different style

Tags: html, css, angular

Can I create one navbar and use it on different pages with different style **in angular** ?

On the first page the دnavbar is transparent and appears after scrolling, but I want it to be white and sticky in the rest of the other pages.

Comment: You can apply styles and attributes based on current route

Answer (score 0):

You can check url and add different navigation components based on current route.

```
constructor(private router: Router ) {
   console.log(this.router.url); //route name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a navbar in the main component, then you can update its sticky behavior with 2 approaches:

**Approach 1 (Preferred way):**

Let's say that you already have many pages where you want your navbar to be sticky or transparent. Going to each page & changing some configs is time-consuming.

Instead, you subscribe to `Router`'s `NavigationEnd` event in `app.component.ts`

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {}

  setNavSticky=true; //Default to true if we have many pages

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(ev=>ev instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((navEndEvent:NavigationEnd)=>{
      if(navEndEvent.url.includes('/home')){
        //Add more pages in condition for which navbar should not be sticky
        this.setNavSticky=false;
      }
      else{
        this.setNavSticky=true;
      }
      
    })
  }
```

Bind the sticky class in the `app.component`'s HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar" [class.sticky]="setNavSticky">
  <header>My main navbar</header>
  ...
</nav>
```

**Approach 2:** Create a utility service at the root level which has the property `isNavbarSticky`. All the pages that want to set it false, can do so by injecting it in their component file.

With approach 2, you have to manually set/unset `isNavbarSticky` in pages that don't want sticky navbar.